# Find the value of:$\frac{|1-z_1||1-z_2||1-z_3|\ldots|1-z_9|}{10}$where $z_k$ is the 10th root of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> $$z_k=\cos\left( \frac{2k\pi}{10}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{10}\right);k\in \{1,2,3,\ldots,9\}$$
>   then find the value of:$$\frac{|1-z_1||1-z_2||1-z_3|\ldots|1-z_9|}{10}$$

Answer: 1

### My attempt:

$$\text{let,  }\frac{|1-z_1||1-z_2||1-z_3|\ldots|1-z_9|}{10}=p$$
$$p^2=\frac{|1-z_1|^2|1-z_2|^2|1-z_3|^2\ldots|1-z_9|^2}{100}$$
$$\implies p^2=\frac{(1-z_1)(1-\overline{z_1})(1-z_2)(1-\overline{z_2})\ldots(1-z_9)(1-\overline{z_9})}{100}\text{,  since } z\overline{z}=|z|^2$$
$$=\frac{\{(1-z_1)(1-z_2)\ldots (1-z_9)\}\{(1-\overline{z_1})(1-\overline{z_2})\ldots (1-\overline{z_9})\}}{100}$$

since $z_k$ is the $10^{th}$ root of unity hence $x^{10}-1=(x-1)(x-z_1)\ldots(x-z_9)$
$$\implies \frac{x^{10}-1}{x-1}=(x-z_1)(x-z_2)\ldots(x-z_9)$$
$$x=1,  \frac{1^{10}-1}{1-1}=(1-z_1)(1-z_2)\ldots(1-z_9)=0/0$$

so you see at this point i am stuck, how do i solve this further

Comment: you can use $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{10}-1}{x-1}$ which by Lhopital' s Rule is $10$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very much the right idea, but the execution was too complicated. Note that
$$x^9+x^8+\cdots +x+1=(x-z_1)(x-z_2)\dots (x-z_9),$$
and let $x=1$.

Comment: nice answer. superb.